# Can the suffix "to do so" change a noun into a verb?

Tags: verbs, nouns, zero-derivation

Consider the following:

> The Cleaners were asked to clean.

Is it valid to use *to do so* instead of *to clean* removing the redundancy from mentioning cleaners and clean in the same sentence?

While I'm a native speaker, I haven't learnt the laws of the English language academically other than standard schooling to the age of 16, so would appreciate the elucidation here.

Comment: What do you mean by "valid"? *To do so* isn't a suffix, it's an infinitive clause. Redundancy here is a semantic issue. Cleaners may be asked to do lots of things besides clean. They could be asked to leave, to sing, or to call the police.

Comment: @deadrat They could, but _do so_ refers back to something that was stated earlier. So unless you'd mentioned leaving, singing, etc., it would default to their expected activity.

Comment: You could say _were asked to do their job_.

Comment: @Barmar Except that we don't have a "something" that was stated earlier. All we have is the statement *The Cleaners were asked to clean*. Replacing "to clean" with *to do so* leaves the *so* without any activity to refer to. It's a reasonable inference that the doing is what cleaners usually do (namely, clean), but that won't solve the syntactic problem and will probably leave readers wondering whether they missed something.

Comment: @deadrat Perhaps it would make more sense if it were written "The people who clean were asked to do so." Then it's clear that "do so" refers to "clean".

Comment: @Barmar Yes, of course. The word *so* links *to do* with another infinitive, so syntactically you have a matching referent.

Answer (score 1):

While it would probably be understood, it seems like a clumsy construction. *to do so* normally refers back to a previously mentioned verb, and *cleaners* is a noun. So you could write:

> The people whose job it is to clean were asked to do so.

Even though *cleaners* means *people whose job it is to clean*, this expansion doesn't come naturally when searching back for an antecedent.

Answer (score 0):

I think the task should be previously explained as to say 'to do so'. 
And it becomes correct if said as: The people whose job is to clean were asked to do that.

Comment: Try and explain your answer, preferably with some supporting statements and references. While opinions are valued, they are not of much help as answers.